# Search query for searchbar in android and php as a backend

Tags: php, android, web-services

> i am developing an android shopping app in which i have taken a search bar to search products like search by brand, or size, or by name etc. I am using php as a backend for the application i.e. web services in php. what query should i use for this search by brand or by name in this scenario ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for search by brand

```
select * from productstable where brand in ('a','b','c','etc') AND Productname like '%name%';
```

for search by size

```
select * from productstable where size in (1,2,3,4) AND Productname like '%name%';
```

name is the text you are searching for

Comment: please select as accepted if the answer is correct and upvote if the answer helped you in anyway